# Want to extract links and titles from a certain website with lxml and python but cant

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, screen-scraping

I am Yasa James, 14, and I am new to web scraping.
I am trying to extract titles and links from this [website](https://animixplay.to/?q=dr.%20stone).
As an so called "Utako" and a want-to-be programmer, I want to create a program that extract links and titles at the same time. I am currently using lxml because I cant download selenium, limited internet, very slow internet because Im from a province in philippines and I think its faster than other modules that I've used.

here's my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://animixplay.to/dr.%20stone'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = html.fromstring(page.content)

anime = doc.xpath('//*[@id="result1"]/ul/li[1]/p[1]/a/text()')

print(anime)
```

One thing I've noticed is that is I want to grab the value of an element from any of the divs, is it gives out an empty list as an output.

I hope you can help me with this my Seniors. Thank You!

Update:
i used `requests-html` to fix my problem and now its working, Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly are you trying to output from this program?

Comment: Anime Titles and the hrefs inside the li tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that the site you're trying to fetch uses JavaScript to generate the results, which means Selenium is your only option if you want to scrape the HTML. Any static fetching and processing libraries like lxml and beautifulsoup simply do not have the ability to parse the result of JavaScript calls.

Comment: oh, i see. Thank you my Senior. Ive been trying to find a solution for about a week now. Btw are there any libraries that I can use to parse the results in java? I only have 200mb left in my subscription. (sorry if I sound like I dont have manners, Im just not used to talk to people in real life)

Comment: No, unfortunately you need a browser surrogate like Selenium (there's a java version of it).

Comment: oh, Thank you again my Senior. I've learned so much today, Thank you.

Comment: Selenium is probably not the only option. There are several API calls returning the html inside json that the page uses to update. You can likely parse those and get the same data without the need for browser. There is also an end API call returning lists of general related search results.

Comment: can I get more info about that my Senior?